# Session must be bound error using Squeryl

Tags: scala, squeryl

**Update:**
Okay, I fixed the problem I was having, but I'm still not quite sure what I was doing wrong. In any case, I wrote the following method in IRCDB:

```
def tryit[T](p: => T) = {
    Class.forName("org.h2.Driver") //what's the point in this...?

    SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(() =>
        Session.create(java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/irc","ScalaIRC",""), new H2Adapter))

    transaction {
        p
    }
}
```

Then used it like so:

```
 val query = from(IRCDB.channels)(c => select(c))
 IRCDB.tryit {
     for (r <- query) println("chan: " + r.name)
 }
```

And it now works. From my understanding, I believed that once the session was created using the SessionFactory, I'd be able to use `transaction { ... }` anywhere that has the proper import. Apparently, my understanding is incorrect.

If anyone has anything to add please do.

---

So, I just started using Squeryl for a project I'm working on so this might just be an oversight on my part. So, first the code:

I have the following imports:

```
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
import java.sql.Timestamp
import java.sql.DriverManager
import java.util.Date
import org.squeryl.adapters.H2Adapter
import org.squeryl.dsl.{OneToMany, ManyToOne, CompositeKey2}
import org.squeryl._
```

I have the following table defined:

```
class ChannelTable(val id: Long, val name : String,
               val p_mode : Boolean, val s_mode : Boolean,
               val i_mode : Boolean, val t_mode : Boolean,
               val n_mode : Boolean, val m_mode : Boolean,
               val key : Option[String]) extends KeyedEntity[Long] {
    def this() = this(0,"", false, false, false, false, false, false, Some(""))

    lazy val bans:OneToMany[ChannelBanTable] = IRCDB.channelToChanBans.left(this)
    lazy val users = IRCDB.channelUsers.left(this)
    lazy val invites = IRCDB.channelInvites.left(this)
}
```

And the following Schema defined:

```
object IRCDB extends Schema {
    val channels = table[ChannelTable]

    on(channels)(c => declare(
      c.p_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.s_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.i_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.t_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.n_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.m_mode defaultsTo(false),
      c.name is(unique, indexed)
    ))

    def init {
        Class.forName("org.h2.Driver") //what's the point in this...?

        SessionFactory.concreteFactory = Some(() =>
          Session.create(DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:~/irc","ScalaIRC",""), new H2Adapter))
    }
    def getAllChannels = transaction { from(channels)(c => select(c))}
}
```

I have been able to insert into the table with the following at the Console:

```
scala> import db._;import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
import db._
import org.squeryl.PrimitiveTypeMode._
scala> IRCDB.init
scala> transaction { IRCDB.channels.insert(new ChannelTable(0,"#chan_name", false, false, false, false, false, false, None)) }
res3: db.ChannelTable = db.ChannelTable@4
```

I can confirm with the H2 Console that this does indeed occur. However, when I call `IRCDB.getAllChannels` (in both the Scala Console and in code) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: no session is bound to current thread, a session must be created via Session.create 
and bound to the thread via 'work' or 'bindToCurrentThread'
    at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:58)
    at org.squeryl.Session$$anonfun$currentSession$1.apply(Session.scala:117)
    at org.squeryl.Session$$anonfun$currentSession$1.apply(Session.scala:117)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:59)
    at org.squeryl.Session$.currentSession(Session.scala:116)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.org$squeryl$dsl$AbstractQuery$$_dbAdapter(AbstractQuery.scala:136)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery$$anon$1.<init>(AbstractQuery.scala:140)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.iterator(AbstractQuery.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:79)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.foreach(AbstractQuery.scala:27)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:206)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.map(AbstractQuery.scala:27)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:255)
    at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:258)
    at RequestResult$line7$object$.<init>(<console>:12)
    at RequestResult$line7$object$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$line7$object.scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1.apply(Interpreter.scala:980)
    at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:79)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request.loadAndRun(Interpreter.scala:979)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.loadAndRunReq$1(Interpreter.scala:578)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.scala:575)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.reallyInterpret$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:471)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.interpretStartingWith(InterpreterLoop.scala:514)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.command(InterpreterLoop.scala:361)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.processLine$1(InterpreterLoop.scala:242)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.repl(InterpreterLoop.scala:248)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.main(InterpreterLoop.scala:558)
    at scala.tools.nsc.InterpreterLoop.main(InterpreterLoop.scala:609)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.scala.compiler.rt.ConsoleRunner.main(ConsoleRunner.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:115)
```

I don't understand why I would be getting this error if I was able to insert rows into the table doing nearly the same way. If I try to execute `transaction { from(IRCDB.channels)(c => select(c)) }` at the Console I get the same error.

---

**Edit:** I've added the full stack trace. Also, I rewrote the `getAllChannels` function like this:

```
def getAllChannels = transaction { 
  val ret = from(channels)(c => select(c))
  println("sql: " + ret)
  ret
}
```

I still receive an error, but it does print the query out first -- I thought this may be useful:

```
sql: 'QueryExpressionNode[root:1a0d111]:rsm='ResultSetMapper:fdf48d()--
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_name
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_i_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_s_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_key
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_n_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_m_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_id
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_t_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'FieldSelectElement:ChannelTable1_p_mode
        org.squeryl.dsl.ast.FieldSelectElement$$anon$3
    'ViewExpressionNode[sample:ChannelTable[16e3f87]]:rsm='ResultSetMapper:442b95($(1->ChannelTable.name:java.lang.String),$(2->ChannelTable.i_mode:java.lang.Boolean),$(3->ChannelTable.s_mode:java.lang.Boolean),$(4->ChannelTable.key:Option[java.lang.String]),$(5->ChannelTable.n_mode:java.lang.Boolean),$(6->ChannelTable.m_mode:java.lang.Boolean),$(7->ChannelTable.id:java.lang.Long),$(8->ChannelTable.t_mode:java.lang.Boolean),$(9->ChannelTable.p_mode:java.lang.Boolean))--*

Select
  ChannelTable1.name as ChannelTable1_name,
  ChannelTable1.i_mode as ChannelTable1_i_mode,
  ChannelTable1.s_mode as ChannelTable1_s_mode,
  ChannelTable1.key as ChannelTable1_key,
  ChannelTable1.n_mode as ChannelTable1_n_mode,
  ChannelTable1.m_mode as ChannelTable1_m_mode,
  ChannelTable1.id as ChannelTable1_id,
  ChannelTable1.t_mode as ChannelTable1_t_mode,
  ChannelTable1.p_mode as ChannelTable1_p_mode
From
  ChannelTable ChannelTable1
java.lang.RuntimeException: no session is bound to current thread, a session must be created via Session.create 
and bound to the thread via 'work' or 'bindToCurrentThread'
    at scala.Predef$.error(Predef.scala:58)
    at org.squeryl.Session$$anonfun$currentSession$1.apply(Session.scala:117)
    at org.squeryl.Session$$anonfun$currentSession$1.apply(Session.scala:117)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:59)
    at org.squeryl.Session$.currentSession(Session.scala:116)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.org$squeryl$dsl$AbstractQuery$$_dbAdapter(AbstractQuery.scala:136)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery$$anon$1.<init>(AbstractQuery.scala:140)
    at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.iterator(AbstractQuery.scala:138)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:79)
    at org.squeryl....
```

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace? Is there no clue to any line in your code being involved?

Comment: What if you try to call "transaction {IRCDB.getAllChannels}"?

Comment: I've updated the post with the full stack trace. Rustem, I just tried that and I unfortunately get the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's what I suspect, your method :

`def getAllChannels = transaction { from(channels)(c => select(c))}`

is returning an **unevaluated** query, i.e. 
the return type of

`from(channels)(c => select(c))`

is `Query[ChannelTable]`
so the method returns, the transaction is ended, the console tries to print it,
which triggers an evaluation :

```
at org.squeryl.dsl.AbstractQuery.map(AbstractQuery.scala:27)        
at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.inner$1(ScalaRunTime.scala:255)
at scala.runtime.ScalaRunTime$.stringOf(ScalaRunTime.scala:258)
at RequestResult$line7$object$.<init>(<console>:12)
at RequestResult$line7$object$.<clinit>(<console>)
at RequestResult$line7$object.scala_repl_result(<console>)
```

since the transaction is ended, you get the message you are getting.

Try this :

```
def getAllChannels = transaction { 
  val q = from(channels)(c => select(c))
  for(z <- q) {
    println(z)
  }
}
```

Comment: If the theory is correct, I will try to patch Squeryl to that the REPL console's default behavior which is to call 'map' is avoided. It seems that the console, when it calls map on Iterables when the get returned from functions.

Comment: Thanks Max, that was indeed the problem. I had a misconception for how the queries worked. Great library, by the way -- a bit more straight forward than some of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, error appears while printing the result to console and the query was ok. Please, provide full stacktrace.

Comment: Full stack trace is provided.